# Create one header file compiled from two header file - makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm new to makefile and I'm wondering how to create one header file compiled out of two header files like an example below

A.h = b.h c.h

Would it be best to use a cat command within the makefile

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you not just include both header files?

Comment: How would you use the bigger header file!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - Forward declaration is better

Answer (score 1):

Header files tell the code what is possible.

Not how it is possible.

So you do not compile header files.

You compile the how it is possible bits